# Apache2 command such as a2enmod and a2ensite no working its showing command not found in Ubuntu

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am deploying Flask application in Apache2 server during this i need to run a command for enabling *mod_wsgi* by using:

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

but its showing:

```
sudo: a2enmod: command not found
```

please help
thanks

Comment: Are you using the system Apache and is it installed? Is the appropriate system ``mod_wsgi`` package installed?

Comment: For such installation debugging request, please post all details you can: OS (Ok It's Ubuntu), Version ??, Architecture: ??, Harsware ??, Host purpose: Desktop or server? How did you install apache? Etc... (some more observation you could share about your specific case)

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem with using Ubuntu 16.04 in AWS. However, installing apache2 along with libapache2-mod-wsgi and python-dev solved the issue.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi python-dev
```

Then,

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

Comment: After above steps , ```sudo systemctl reload apache2``` will be needed

Answer (score 10):

I share this tips because it append to me :

If you enter into the root account with `su`, the `/usr/sbin` folder is not in the path and the `a2enmod` command is not found...

So you have to use `su -` instead ;)

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you switch to root user as `su root` instead of `su -` on Debian Buster

Answer (score 2):

### Installation debugging

For asking about installation debugging, you have to post (and think) about

- Architecture (hardware)
- OS with version
- Host attibution (server, desktop, other)
- Procedure followed for installation
- Software (apache) version

### Anyway

You could try to *reinstall* your package. If under Ubuntu, you could try:

```
sudo apt update &&
    sudo apt reinstall apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Then rerun:

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```