# a2enmod command not found in apache server using cpanel in linux vps

Tags: apache, cpanel, vps

after going to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  and even after changing

```
Allow override none -> Allow override All , and then restarting the server using 

service httpd restart
```

and then i type the command

```
 a2enmod proxy
```

then i get an error :

```
bash- a2enmod command not found. .
```

Can you please help me? i am getting an error in the  developer tools console when i am using web-sockets and so for that i need to enable web-sockets proxy.

Comment: Go and try SuperUser instead of StackOverflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache2 command such as a2enmod and a2ensite no working its showing command not found in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138215/apache2-command-such-as-a2enmod-and-a2ensite-no-working-its-showing-command-not)

Comment: I had the same problem too! worked after using sudo. Did nothing else. Just used sudo a2enmod. worked like a charm

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, and this answer solved my issue:

[Apache2 command such as a2enmod and a2ensite no working its showing command not found in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138215/apache2-command-such-as-a2enmod-and-a2ensite-no-working-its-showing-command-not)

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Then,

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

Then, you might also want to try `sudo a2enmod` instead of just `a2enmod`

Answer (score 6):

On Debian `a2enmod` is located at `/usr/sbin/a2enmod` and sometimes `/usr/sbin` is not in your **PATH**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case below lines worked

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```