# Get real user ip of Nuxt application through apache reverse proxy in Laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, vue.js, nuxt.js, reverse-proxy

I am using Nuxtjs as frontend of my application and Laravel framework as backend.
I hosted my application on an Apache Centos server.
After running application with pm2 on localhost:3000 I can not get real ip of user in Laravel.

My Centos version:

```
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

My Apache version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
```

My VirtualHost in apache:

```
<VirtualHost MY_IP:80>
    UserDir public_html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
    RemoteIPProxiesHeader X-Forwarded-By
    <LocationMatch "/">
        allow from all
        Satisfy any
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

My `boot` method in `AppServiceProvider` in Laravel

```
public function boot()
{
    Request::setTrustedProxies(['REMOTE_ADDR'], Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
}
```

But after these steps when I use  `request()->ip()` or `request()->getClientIp()`
in Laravel, it gives me server ip.
How can i get real user ip in my Laravel application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR http header variable that you looking for.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

or

```
 $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]
```

if its doesn't exists Apache's **mod_remoteip** module can help this header variables
more about: https://www.globo.tech/learning-center/x-forwarded-for-ip-apache-web-server/

Comment: Thanks @Mustafa for your reply. but there is no `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` index in $_SERVER variable

Comment: i am using same setup like you nuxt + laravel in my application only difference is nginx 
 so i am nginx guy but is this helps ? https://www.globo.tech/learning-center/x-forwarded-for-ip-apache-web-server/

Comment: in my apache web server: `a2enmod: command not found`

Comment: try with sudo if its not there is a some related topics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022485/a2enmod-command-not-found-in-apache-server-using-cpanel-in-linux-vps

Comment: i used with sudo but it said `command not found`. i listed my apache modules and i saw this `remoteip_module (static)`