# Compile and install the Apache2 from source code, but not full tools are installed (a2enmod, a2ensite, a2enconf ..)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, apache2.4

I'm sorry, but my English is not very good. I want setup Apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LT, but I have the following problem:

I have install the Apache2 package on Ubuntu, use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Once installed, tools like a2enmod, a2ensite, a2enconf ... are also installed.

But I compile and install the Apache2 from source code, tools like a2enmod, a2ensite, a2enconf ... are not installed. I use the command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2/2.4.46 \
--enable-load-all-modules
make
sudo make install
```

I have downloaded source code from https://salsa.debian.org/apache-team/apache2/-/tree/master/ . It’s both original source and debian source.
Can someone help me compile and install the Apache2 package from source code with full tools are installed. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo a2enmod
```

I had a similar problem with a Debian system where Apache2 was compiled from source. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411977